# .htaccess redirect to HTTPS is removing / between domain and URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect my HTTP to HTTPS using .htaccess. The problem I am having is when a user adds to a path do the domain the "/" between the domain and the path is removed after redirect. How do I get my rewrite to preserve the slash after the domain?

```
http://www.example.com/blog/post
```

rewrites to:

```
https://www.example.comblog/post
```

Below is the .htaccess file I am using.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply force the trailing slash, so no matter what a user does, it will add a `/` to the end of your URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

It will do this use a permanent 301 redirection. Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: Do I not need "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off" and "RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/"

Comment: Keep that. The above is simply forcing the `/` at the end of the URLs.